# SQL Query - Help Needed for retrieval of values in a text field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like follows:

```
NAME(varchar(6),  STRING(varchar(250)

ABCD   '1     2     1    173  1      8  9   1     1     2     4    7      1   3.....'
APLC   '1  3 11       34        1  4   99          33     23        111       12   6 7 8....'
```

the string continues with this up to 250 characters.

What I am trying to do is get the values and there respective positions from this string.

I know I can use `Charindex` but that gives me only the first position of a number in the string.

e.g.

```
Select Charindex ('2',STRING) where Name = ABCD
```

ANSWER = 7

But what I'm looking for is something like a table that have the following in for each Name

```
Name  Position   Value 
---------------------------    
ABCD,   7,         2
ABCD,   1,         1
ABCD,   13,        1
ABCD,   18,        1
ABCD,   19,        7
```

Any ideas welcome :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like string manipulation are often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: @marc_s +100 for patience and for the will to correct new members. :-)

Comment: Sorry guys i'm new hehe. This is Microsoft SQL 2008

Comment: So for future reference: **always** define your environment - what software and which version you're using. People trying to help you here cannot see your screen, nor can they look into your PC. It's up to you to provide the relevant info for someone to help you. Thanks for listening!

Comment: user1546143, what is the range of numbers used in "STRING" columns? I understand that number of spaces between numbers is random?

Comment: The string can contain up to 250 characters each position can hold a value of 1 to 9, and yes the spaces is random. This is a string file that represents security for e.g. if in position 15 of this string your value is say 8 you have certain permissions to do something, if in position 5 you have no value you dont have permission to access something for e.g.

Comment: but I see "173" and "99" there. should those be treated as two numbers or as five digits then?

Comment: @Kuba so you must view it as "1" = position XX "7" is position xy and "3" is position yy so each number from 1 - 9 represent a position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little help of a numbers table it could look like this.

```
select T.Name,
       N.N as Position,
       substring(T.STRING, N.N, 1) as Value
from YourTable as T
  cross apply Numbers as N
where N.N between 1 and 250 and
      substring(T.STRING, N.N, 1) <> ' '
```

Working sample with table variable and `master..spt_values` as a numbers table.

```
declare @T table
(
  NAME varchar(6),
  STRING varchar(250)
)

insert into @T values
('ABCD', '1     2     1    173  1      8  9   1     1     2     4    7      1   3'),
('APLC', '1  3 11       34        1  4   99          33     23        111       12   6 7 8')

;with Numbers(N) as
(
  select Number 
  from master..spt_values
  where type = 'P'
)
select T.Name,
       N.N as Position,
       substring(T.STRING, N.N, 1) as Value
from @T as T
  cross apply Numbers as N
where N.N between 1 and 250 and
      substring(T.STRING, N.N, 1) <> ' '
```

Comment: Yes, I think that is what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

This approach would work for multi-digit numbers.  If `173` should result in three result rows, check Mikael Eriksson's or podiluska's answer.

```
; with   cte as
         ( 
         select  1 as start
         ,       case 
                 when patindex('%[0-9] %', string) > 0 then patindex('%[0-9] %', string)
                 else len(string)
                 end as [length]
         ,       name
         ,       string
         from    YourTable
         union all
         select  start + [length] as start
         ,       case 
                 when patindex('%[0-9] %', 
                     substring(string, start + [length], len(string)-start + [length])) 
                     > 0 then patindex('%[0-9] %', 
                     substring(string, start + [length], len(string)-start + [length])) 
                 else len(string)-start + [length]
                 end as [length]
         ,       name
         ,       string
         from    cte
         where   start + [length] < len(string)
         )
select  Name 
,       start + patindex('%[0-9]%', substring(string, [start], [length])) - 1 as Position
,       ltrim(substring(string, [start], [length])) as Value
from     cte
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd453/8/0)

Answer (score 0):

Where #t is your table...

```
;WITH numbers ( n ) AS 
(
     select 1 as n
     union all
     select 1 + n FROM numbers WHERE n < 250 
)
select name, n as position, SUBSTRING(string,n,1) as value
from #t, numbers
where SUBSTRING(string,n,1)<>' '
order by Name, n
option (maxrecursion 250)
```

If, on the other hand, you want to treat consecutive numbers as being a one number...

```
;WITH Pieces(name, pn, start, [stop], string) AS 
(
   SELECT name, 1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', string),string from #t
   UNION ALL
   SELECT pieces.name, pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(' ', pieces.string, stop + 1), pieces.string
   FROM Pieces
    inner join #t on pieces.name = #t.name
   WHERE stop > 0
)
select * 
from
(    SELECT name, start as position,
           SUBSTRING(string, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 300 END) AS value
           FROM Pieces
) v
where RTRIM(value)>''
```

Comment: @Andomar yes. I originally had one that worked for sequences of numbers (see edit history), but then i re-read the question and from the example set, single numbers is what is requested.

Comment: Thx alot for all the feedback guys! Greatly appreciated, ill try your solutions and provide feedback. Greetings from africa